# ConTeXt: Optional XML in two columns

Tags: context, xml

I have the following XML data:

```
\startbuffer[demo]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
<Reading>
<Header>Foo</Header>
<Source>From Source #1</Source>
<Line>Line #1</Line>
<Line>Line #2</Line>
<Line>Line #3</Line>
</Reading>
<Reading>
<Header>Bar</Header>
<Line>Line #4</Line>
<Line>Line #5</Line>
<Line>Line #6</Line>
</Reading>
</Book>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
    \xmlsetsetup{#1}{Book|Reading|Header|Source|Line}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}
```

I want to put the `<Header>` and `<Source>` in two columns, but as you see with the second reading, sometimes there is no source. I defined a `\ReadingHeader` and was going to use:

```
\startxmlsetups xml:Reading
    \startReadingHeader
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Source
    \xmlflush{#1}
    \stopReadingHeader
\stopxmlsetups
```

...but this doesn't work if there is no `<Source>`. I'm sure I'm doing this all wrong. What is the right way?

Comment: Easy solution (for processing): If the source belongs to the header make it a child element of Header. If you can't change the format you may simply open the reading header when encountering Reading and close it on the first occurrence of Line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends a bit on what is the desired output when `<source>` is missing. You can use `\xmlfilter{#1}{...}` or `\xmldoif...` etc. Here is one example:

```
\startbuffer[demo]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
<Reading>
<Header>Foo</Header>
<Source>From Source #1</Source>
<Line>Line #1</Line>
<Line>Line #2</Line>
<Line>Line #3</Line>
</Reading>
<Reading>
<Header>Bar</Header>
<Line>Line #4</Line>
<Line>Line #5</Line>
<Line>Line #6</Line>
</Reading>
</Book>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{Book|Reading}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\startxmlsetups xml:Book
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\definemixedcolumns[ReadingHeader][balance=yes]

\startxmlsetups xml:Reading
  \startReadingHeader
    \xmlfilter{#1}{/Header/command(xml:Header)}
    \column
    \xmlfilter{#1}{/Source/command(xml:Source)}
  \stopReadingHeader
    \xmlfilter{#1}{/Line/command(xml:Line)}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Source
  [\xmlflush{#1}]
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Header
    \bold{\xmlflush{#1}}\space
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Line
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{demo}{}
```

which gives

[image]